Mongodb Scala Driver pushes seq as a single value to an array rather than individual element
Here is how I'm trying to push a seq of ids to an array in MongoDB
val resIdFuture = formsCol.insertMany(documents).toFuture().map {
        res =>
          println("[InsertResult] ", res.getInsertedIds)
          res.getInsertedIds.values()
      }
      // Now update forms in org
      resIdFuture.onComplete {
        case Success(formIds) =>
          val orgRes = orgCol.updateOne(equal("_id", orgId), pushEach("forms", formIds.toArray.toSeq)).toFuture().map {
            res => println("Result of org form ids push: ", res)
          }
          orgRes.onComplete {
            case Success(rs) => println("Complete result", rs)
            case Failure(ex) => println("Exception while updating org forms: ", ex)
          }
        case Failure(ex) => println("Exception while inserting forms: ", ex)
      }

Instead of pushing each element from formIds whole seq is pushed as an individual value to the array. How do I resolve this?

Shouldn't it be just formIds.toArray instead of formIds.toArray.toSeq? If you expect that the scala driver should treat Sequence as a 'collection' to iterate over for values rather than just a 'collection of values' (aka list, array, etc.) then it could be feature request for the driver, or a bug.

I did that itself before. Then was doing hit and trial to explicitly make it a Seq.
